# specifying Windows Version.Build

Tags: vb.net, windows, desktop-application

i have a problem with finding the correct form to tell my app to write a diferent thing in a text box according to windows build

code is:

```
Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim OSVer As Version = Environment.OSVersion.Version

    'Windows 10
    If OSVer.Build >= 10240 Then
        My.Forms.Main.WinVer.Text = "Detected Windows 10"
    End If

    'Windows 8 / 8.1
    If OSVer.Build <= 10000 And OSVer.Build >= 8000 Then
        My.Forms.Main.WinVer.Text = "Windows 8 / 8.1 are not supported yet"
    End If

    'Windows 7
    If OSVer.Build >= 7600 And OSVer.Build < 8000 Then
        My.Forms.Main.WinVer.Text = "Detected Windows 7"
    End If

    'OLD WINDOWS VERSION
    If OSVer.Build < 7600 Then
        My.Forms.Main.WinVer.Text = "Your Windows is not supported"
    End If
End Sub
```

i'm on windows 10 (build 10240), after using this code, the app showed me the text of Windows 8/8.1 situation

How to correct this?

Comment: **More info:**
- Windows 10 Pro (**build 10240**)
- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- Language: VB.NET

Comment: Code looks fine, what's the value of OSVer.Build when you step through this code?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It is correct, Microsoft does not want you to tell your customer that your program does not run correctly on Windows 10.  They've done a *lot* of work to ensure that your program does in fact run fine on Win10.  They used to spend an enormous amount of time creating appcompat shims for these kind of version tests, not anymore.   If you don't want to support Win10 then you need to state so in your system requirements.  They cannot otherwise stop you from using FileVersionInfo on an operating system executable like kernel32.dll

Comment: @Eric My os is windows 10 (10240) so according to this code i must get the output `Detected Windows 10` but it's giving me `Windows 8 / 8.1 are not supported`

Comment: @Yacoub this looks the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx), you have to target your application properly to get the expected results.

After you setup the manifest properly, you can use the `OSVersion.Version.Major` and `OSVersion.Version.Minor` properties to check the operating system. The version numbers are specified in the above mentioned article in tabular form.

Comment: wow i found that everything is right but when i launch the app from debug folder

Comment: maybe it's a matter with build configurations