# How to detect Windows 10 Anniversary Update?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-10

I have a VB.NET application that uses Sticky Notes, which have changed in Windows 10 "Anniversary Update".

How can I detect Windows 10 "Anniversary Update" vs. Windows 10 vs. older versions of Windows? (I need this to start Sticky Notes in the previous way or in the actual way).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109938/specifying-windows-version-build) talks about distinguishing previous versions of Windows, but doesn't cover the Anniversary Update.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx explains it in details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [specifying Windows Version.Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109938/specifying-windows-version-build)

Comment: the other question explains it. Anniversary Update is Build 14393, add this simple check to your code ;)

Comment: @magicandre1981 is the same link I checked before and linked in the question ;). As far as I can see, the question and the answer are not providing an answer able to distinguish Win 10 Anniversary from plain Win 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom solution [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73000/Getting-Operating-System-Version-Info-Even-for-Win) use the `dll` from that codeproject link. And you can get `Name`, `Version` `BuildVersion` `ProgramBits` and many more, by this you can easily compare.

```
var name = OSVersionInfo.Name;
var version = OSVersionInfo.Version;
var build = OSVersionInfo.BuildVersion;
```

Comment: The example is a bit too big for my needs, but checking the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion (provided in your example) was the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check the window version it should be 10.0.14393 after the update

```
ver | find "14393"
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" [Do your stuff]
```